# Any free library to generate tokens

Tags: c#, .net, security, project, token

Tokens can be used for many purposes in a web application some of them below

1. Generate short verification code for signup's
2. Verification code for mobile authentication
3. Avoid CSRF through use of request mapped token
4. Email link validation and many many more

I am on the lookout for one that will do this for me. A token is a short alphanumeric string that is unique, random and configurable. Does anyone know one for .NET, C#

Comment: @All ok may be reason for downvote will be nice. Either my question is incorrect, I don't have time to write my own wrapper and test it. So why not reuse components that others have written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally i used authentification with Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail, Facebook and Twitter and thats the way they work, they generate authetntification tokens, and of course @ no cost. Of course MSDN also teaches you how to implement a custom Token Generator if you really need that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731872.aspx

Comment: what makes you think i am talking about tokens in regards to yahoo or gmail

Comment: because you need some token, so if you dont want to write your own and want them generated elsewhere it is an option(thats what my made me think that), i also gave you a custom token implementation option.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just used a Guid and base64 encode it?

Comment: Why base64? Just remove the `-`s et voilà!